# Read the remaining integers from input and append each integer to user_guesses in that order

Tags: python, string, list

Ex: If the input is:

```
3
9
5
2
```

then the output is:

```
user_guesses: [9, 5, 2]
```

Note: Remember to correctly close all parentheses.

My work:

```py
num_guesses = int(input())
user_guesses = []

user_guesses.remove[0]

print(f'user_guesses: {user_guesses}')
```

Comment: Please post the whole task text and format the code snippet. Unfortunately currently it's hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What happened when you ran your code?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a for loop / while loop to enter the no of values you want to save. have a list where you will store these value

below code, take the input from user where it ask for no of value he want to enter and then declare a list to store value. then using loops, take input from  the user and append it to the list. and then finally print the store list

```
times = int(input("Enter the no of values you want to read: "))
values = []
for _ in range(times):
    value = int(input())
    values.append(value)

print(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to input one value at a time then you need some way of breaking out of the input loop. You can do this in various ways. Here's one:

```
user_guesses = []

while guess := input('Enter a value or <return> to finish: '):
    try:
        user_guesses.append(int(guess))
    except ValueError:
        print(f'{guess} is not an integer')

print(f'user_guesses: {user_guesses[-3:]}')
```

**Console:**

```
3
9
5
2

user_guesses: [9, 5, 2]
```

**Note:**

If you require integer values then you should validate them